# How to list files directory/files using Apache Common VFS

Tags: java, ftp, file-transfer, jsch, apache-commons-vfs

I am using Apache Common VFS and successfully connected to the server.
I already read docs but I'm stuck in this code.  How i can list directory/files?

```java
Session session = null;
FileSystemManager fsManager = null;
FileSystem fs = null;
try {
    String host = "host_here";
    int port = 22;

    String userStr = "user_here";
    char [] username = userStr.toCharArray();

    String passStr = "password_here";
    char [] password = passStr.toCharArray();

    session = SftpClientFactory.createConnection(host, port, username, password, null);
    //session.connect();

    System.out.println("Connected to the server");

    FileSystemOptions opts = new FileSystemOptions();
    fsManager = VFS.getManager();
    FileObject file = fsManager.resolveFile("ftp://"+userStr+":"+passStr+"@"+host+"/home/", opts);    

    // .... whats next i do here? .....

} catch (Exception e) {
    session.disconnect();
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Please help me,
Thank you before :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

List of files can be displayed by using [FileObject#getChildren()](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/apidocs/index.html) method.

```
FileSystemOptions opts = new FileSystemOptions();
fsManager = VFS.getManager();

// List all the files in that directory.Try to give the directory path  
FileObject localFileObject=fsManager.resolveFile("ftp://"+userStr+":"+passStr+"@"+host+"/home");
FileObject[] children = localFileObject.getChildren();
for ( int i = 0; i < children.length; i++ ){
    System.out.println( children[ i ].getName().getBaseName() );
}
// End of List Files.

FileObject file = fsManager.resolveFile("ftp://"+userStr+":"+passStr+"@"+host+"/home/", opts);
```

My suggestion would be to Use [JSCH](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) framework which is best for SFTP operations. As this `Apache Common VFS` inherently used this framework.The complexcity will be greatly reduced by `JSCH`.

Comment: Thank you srinivas, Now i use JSCH :D
But i wonder, how to save directory(not file) to destination directory?

Comment: You mean create new directory or save a directory with already some files in it?

Comment: Yes, like that. Its possible?